# modify php natcasesort so 'letters only' come first

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array

```
$arr=array(
"Mega XYZ no number",
"Classic no Number",
"Doppel 80x200cm",
"Classic 100x200cm",
"Mega 240x250",
"Classic 85x200cm",
"Mega 40x250",
"Profi 60x235cm",
"Mega 140x250",
);
```

and would like to have the following order:

```
Classic no Number   
Classic 85x200cm  
Classic 100x200cm    
Doppel 80x200cm  
Mega XYZ no number  
Mega 40x250  
Mega 140x250  
Mega 240x250    
Profi 60x235cm
```

php's function `natcasesort()` almost gets it done right EXCEPT '`Classic no Number`' and '`Mega XYZ no number`' won't be the first in their 'group'! I'd like to have items without any number in it to appear before their alphabetically group-items with numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's it:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    $arr1 = str_split($a);
    $arr2 = str_split($b);

    $number1 = "";
    $number2 = "";

    for($i = 0; $i < count($arr1); $i++){
        $char1 = $arr1[$i];
        $char2 = $arr2[$i];
        if(is_numeric($char1) && !is_numeric($char2)){
            return 1;
        }
        if(!is_numeric($char1) && is_numeric($char2)){
            return -1;
        }
        else if(is_numeric($char1) && is_numeric($char2)){
            $number1 .= $char1;
            $number2 .= $char2;
        }
        else {
            if($char1 != $char2){
                if(!empty($number1) && !empty($number2)){
                    $number1 = intval($number1);
                    $number2 = intval($number2);
                    return ($number1 < $number2) ? -1 : 1;
                }
                return ($char1 < $char2) ? -1 : 1;
            }
            else {
                if(!empty($number1) && !empty($number2) && $number1 != $number2){
                    $number1 = intval($number1);
                    $number2 = intval($number2);
                    return ($number1 < $number2) ? -1 : 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

usort($arr, "cmp");
```

Comment: I got this using your code:`Array
(
    [0] => Classic 85x200cm
    [1] => Classic 100x200cm
    [2] => Classic a Number
    [3] => Classic no Number
    [4] => Doppel 80x200cm
    [5] => Mega 40x250
    [6] => Mega 240x250
    [7] => Mega 140x250
    [8] => Mega XYZ
    [9] => Profi 60x235cm
)`

Comment: It's exactly what the op asked. :)

Comment: nop... he wants letters first, then numbers. Take a second look ;)

Comment: Thanks. Almost! With you're code 'Mega 240x250' comes before 'Mega 140x250' which should not because 140 is a smaller number than 240! The Rest is good.

Comment: Are you getting the desired result with the updated code? For me it's doing the same error.

Comment: No, works for me :-? tested it... he forgot to say `usort($arr, 'cmp');` and then you can print your array, but I guess that you can do that...

Comment: Perfect! In my test environment I had the natcasesort() before you're code. Now it's working :-) But I'm wondering, shouldn't the code give the same result no matter how mixed up the array was before?

Comment: Could you try to add natcasesort() before you're code? If you still get the desired result?

Comment: Yes, the problem is present. I'm investigating.

Comment: @Davide: Works like a charm now :-) thumbs up